# Static IP for USB Tethering

Tags: usb, dhcp, tethering

On my Xubuntu (16.04), how can I disable DHCP for an USB device (enp0s20u3u4u1) created from a USB tethering android connexion ?

Comment: The need is basically to avoid DHCP changes on the resolv.conf and default route.

Comment: Is all-manual resolv.conf handling acceptable to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use the NetManager GUI.**

First, check the provided DHCP configuration so that you can use the same configuration for your manual IP assignment.

Make a note of these IPv4 settings:

- IP address
- Netmask
- Gateway

While there are a number of methods, these commands will provide the information:

**IP Address and NetMask:**

```
$ ifconfig
```

**Gateway:**

```
$ route -n
```

**Now to create your custom configuration:**

(click) The **Network Icon** in the Navigation bar -> (click) **Edit** ->

(click) Add -> (Select the connection type for your `enp0s20u3u4u1` choice) **Ethernet** ->

(click) **Create** -> (Type in a name for your new configuration) **MYIP** ->

Choose your device **enp0s20u3u4u1** from the **Device drop-down**) ->

(click the tap) **IPv4 Settings** -> (for the Method choose from the drop-down **Manual**) ->

(click) **Add** -> (Insert your **Address**, **Netmask**, and **Gateway** from the old configuration found above.  Use your own uniqe IP, changing only the number after the last dot so that you say on the same network.  Press ENTER after each entry) ->

(type in your desired **DNS Servers** and **Search Domains**) -> (click) **Save** -> (click) **Close**

---

The steps might appear complicated, but while looking at the GUI interface, it should all fall in place.

After you have created the new connection, you can use the Network Icon to disconnect from your current DHCP default and connect to the custom configuration.

When reboot it'll default to the last connection used.